# Concept of like statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array and would like to use the same concept as a like in SQL to find certain characters in a string.

This what I'm trying to use:

```
if (nameArray[i].nameInfo.fullName ^= "Bob") {
   // TODO: some code.
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: string contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/javascript-string-contains)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (nameArray[i].nameInfo.fullName.indexOf("Bob") != -1) {
    //todo : some code.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Answer (score 1):

Beware that indexOf is not supported by earlier versions of IE. In which case the following code can be included.

```
if(!Array.indexOf){
        Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
            for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
                if(this[i]==obj){
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Ps. i was going to post this as a comment but don't have enough reputation to do so yet :-/

Comment: It's impossible to format that much code legibly in a comment anyway.

Comment: That's what links are for :-P

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are looking for, but it seems from your code that you want to find a first name.  If this was just an example, and you don't want a first name, I probably won't be answering your question well.  I couldn't find anything about `if(foo ^= bar)` online.

It would be easy to get the first word in a string (like a first name) through `var firstName = name.split(' ')[0]`.

To find out how similar a string is to another string, [this](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/levenshtein/) was suggested in another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042873/javascript-text-similarity-algorithm/5042897#5042897).  I don't know anything about it.

Personally if given the task of finding if a first name is similar to a string given, I would compare similarity of both strings after `string.toLowerCase()`, and/or compare each character.  The library above seems much better if you are looking for overall similarity, but a custom function would allow much more control over similarity detection.

```
function checkSimilarity(str, target, tolerance) {
    for(x=0; x < str.length();x++) {
        if(str.split('')[x].toLowerCase() == target.split('')[x].toLowerCase()) {
            similar += 1;
        }
    }
    if(similar => (target.length() * tolerance)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

No clue how the function above works, but it's what I thought of.  (Tolerance needs to be between `0` and `1`)