# Stackoverflow's "related entries" algorithm in client-side Javascript?

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, client-side

Been googling this for a bit, but i dont think i know how to phrase my question:

I have a client-side javascript app with an array of questions.

```
var questions = [
    'How are you?',
    'Where are you?',
    'How far away is the sun?'
];
```

I would like to compare a new question against the array of existing questions:

```
var newQuestion = "How are you doing today?";
```

Is there an existing client-side javascript library that will copmare the new question to the array of existing questions and return a result like:

```
[
    {
        original: "How are you?",
        similarity: .80
    },
    {
        original: "Where are you?",
        similarity: .71
    },
    {
        original: "How far away is the sun?",
        similarity: .13
    }
]
```

Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: How do you want to compute this ["similarity"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures)?

Comment: Is the similarity based on just the words and their order, or do you actually wish to analyze the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: based on the individual words, i would think

Comment: Isn't that what the question is?

Comment: What about this library : https://github.com/joshaven/string_score  found in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859561/getting-the-closest-string-match

Comment: @aadit-m-shah based on just the words and their order, yes

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript text similarity Algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042873/javascript-text-similarity-algorithm)

Comment: What you are looking for is called "Edit distance".

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I don't think edit distance will capture this particularly well.  Levenshtein and similar algorithms are not meant for this level of comparison.  Unfortunately, I don't think there is any easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [koopajah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606729/koopajah):

[String_Score](http://github.com/joshaven/string_score) seems to get the job done

> [koopajah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606729/koopajah): What about this library : github.com/joshaven/string_score found in stackoverflow.com/questions/5859561/